# How can set image according to format in SimplePdfViewerControl in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When I tried to view image in PdfViewer with Letter Format then Image is bluring. while when I tried viewing without defined format then picture is clear.

**My Code**

```
private async void Load(PdfDocument pdfDoc)
{
    try
    {
        PdfPages.Clear();

        for (uint i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                    
            var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);

            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            //PdfPageRenderOptions pdfPageRenderOptions = new PdfPageRenderOptions();
            {
                await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);
                await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }
            PdfPages.Add(image);
        }
    }
```

**This Code Belong to Format set**

```cs
StorageFile ImageFile;
var storageFolder = await KnownFolders.GetFolderForUserAsync(null, KnownFolderId.PicturesLibrary);
StorageFolder projectFolder = await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(imageLocation, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile file = await projectFolder.GetFileAsync(item);

if (file == null) return;
                       
var Stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
Stream imageStream = stream.AsStreamForRead();
BitmapImage sourceImage = new BitmapImage();                    
PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(imageStream);
PdfSection section1 = doc.Sections.Add();                       
section1.PageSettings.Size = PdfPageSize.Letter;                       
page = section1.Pages.Add();
PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;                       
//Draw the image           
if (fileType == Constants.PrescriptionType.Prescription.GetHashCode())
    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, page.Graphics.ClientSize.Width, page.Graphics.ClientSize.Height);                       
else
    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, page.Graphics.ClientSize.Width, page.Graphics.ClientSize.Height);
```

Thank You

Comment: *with Letter Format* -- which line of code is related?

Comment: @LeiYang  edited Please observe.